# How to convert a JSON to a SOAP?

Tags: json, web-services, soap, webserver

I am trying to convert a JSON string to a SOAP web service.
The scenario is: I have a web service in java requesting information from a pl/sql. So everytime the java web service requests something from the pl/sql server the data come as JSON.

Before i start to try to develop a SOAP webservice from the scratch i decided to ask here if exist any simple way to convert the JSON to a SOAP.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I know of a simple way, but it's not free.  There is a product on the market from a company called Layer 7 that handles all sorts of conversions like this.  Again, this is not a cheap solution, but it is very good at it.  With any luck, you'll find a more open source way, but I don't know of any of those.